Why can't generate source features?
project structure:

category.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
   <feature id="com.test.A.feature" version="0.0.0">
      <category name="com.test.A.repository"/>
   </feature>
   <feature id="com.test.A.feature.source" version="0.0.0">
      <category name="com.test.A.repository"/>
   </feature>
   <category-def name="com.test.A.repository" label="Test A"/>
</site>

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>build</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <tycho.version>4.0.10</tycho.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>com.test.A</module>
        <module>com.test.A.feature</module>
        <module>com.test.A.repository</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <format>yyyyMMdd-HHmm</format>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>plugin-source</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>plugin-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>feature-source</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>feature-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>

build:
mvn clean verify

error:

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] build 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ............................... SUCCESS [  0.126 s]
[INFO] [bundle] A 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT .......................... SUCCESS [  2.514 s]
[INFO] [feature] A Feature 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT ................. SUCCESS [  0.507 s]
[INFO] [updatesite] com.test.A.repository.eclipse-repository 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT FAILURE [  0.079 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.819 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-11-27T19:44:00+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Cannot resolve dependencies of project com.test:com.test.A.repository.eclipse-repository:eclipse-repository:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]  with context {osgi.os=win32, osgi.ws=win32, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, osgi.arch=x86_64, org.eclipse.update.install.sources=true}
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.test.A.repository.eclipse-repository raw:0.0.1.'SNAPSHOT'/format(n[.n=0;[.n=0;[-S]]]):0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.test.A.repository.eclipse-repository raw:0.0.1.'SNAPSHOT'/format(n[.n=0;[.n=0;[-S]]]):0.0.1-SNAPSHOT requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.test.A.feature.source.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found: See log for details
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

Why isn't A source feature automatically generated?
I referenced these articles:
tycho-source-plugin
11.5. Building source features
Tycho 12: Build source features
there seems to be no relevant omissions. Am I missing something? Thanks.
Solution:
need tycho-p2-plugin:p2-metadata
...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>p2-metadata</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>p2-metadata</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
...

While the problem is solved, I still don't know what it actually did, does anyone know? Thanks.
